# BigQuery Converting UTC Time to Local time

Tags: function, datetime, timezone, google-bigquery, utc

I was wondering if anybody knows a way or has a function that automatically converts a BigQuery UTC timestamp to a local Standard or Daylight saving timezone (PDT/PST in my case).

Basically automatically deducting 7 or 8 hours from UTC to give PDT or PST based on the time of the year.

I know there are many ways I could implement this but I was wondering if anybody knew of any easy, clean and quick way in BigQuery environment.

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using [standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/enabling-standard-sql) (as of sep 2016) you have access to timezone functions such as `DATE(timestamp_expression[, timezone])`:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT DATETIME("2008-12-25 15:30:00+07", "America/Los_Angeles") as date;
```

documentation is [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#date-timestamp).

Comment: This does not (just) convert the timestamp, which is presumbably what you want. It takes in a timestamp and outputs a date.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin there was a typo in the response. The Datetime function converts the +07 notation timezone in the given timezone string mentioned in the param.